How can I enforce equal bandwidth allocation among all connected users in a mixed-integer optimization model?
I am a network engineer who is currently working in a network optimization porblem. Here I got a binary decision matrix that contain some binary decision variable $A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{a_{11}}}&{{a_{12}}}\\
{{a_{21}}}&{{a_{22}}}
\end{array}} \right]$ and another decision matrix $B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{\beta _{11}}}&{{\beta _{12}}}\\
{{\beta _{21}}}&{{\beta _{22}}}
\end{array}} \right]$ where each continuous decision variable ${\beta _{ij}} \in \left[ {0,1} \right]$. Specifically speaking, $a_{mn}$ stand for the connection decision between user $m$ and server $n$ and $\beta_{ij}$ stand for the ammount of received bandwdith. Note that the total bandwidth are normallize so that ${\beta _{11}} + {\beta _{12}} + {\beta _{21}} + {\beta _{22}} \le 1$. Furthermore, the bandwidth are only allocated for the connected user and so ${\beta _{ij}} \le {a_{ij}}$. Now, how can I enforce the constraint "For any user that are connected then their allocated bandwidth should be equal" ?
For example if $A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{array}} \right]$ then $B = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{1}{3}}&{\frac{1}{3}}\\
0&{\frac{1}{3}}
\end{array}} \right]$
Could anyone suggest a good formulation for this case ?
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

It's another case of load balancing / fairness formula wise, but the grouping is different.

Exactly equal or approximately equal? Also, in your example the betas total to 1. Is there anything in your model that might cause the betas to total to less than 1?

Well frankly I would prefer the band with to be exactly equal.  The sum is less than one because there are some edge case when the system does not even use all the bandwidth. Bandwidth is a luxury resource.

You can introduce two non-negative continuous variables to represent the difference between two variables in matrix $B$ and then to give a huge penalty ($M$) for each in minimized objective function.
For example,
$d^{+}_{11,12} \geq \beta_{11} - \beta_{12}$ and $d^{-}_{11,12} \geq \beta_{12} - \beta_{11}$.
$d^{+}_{11,21} \geq \beta_{11} - \beta_{21}$ and $d^{-}_{11,21} \geq 
\beta_{21} - \beta_{11}$.
$d^{+}_{11,22} \geq \beta_{11} - \beta_{22}$ and $d^{-}_{11,22} \geq \beta_{22} - \beta_{11}$.
$d^{+}_{12,21} \geq \beta_{12} - \beta_{21}$ and $d^{-}_{12,21} \geq \beta_{21} - \beta_{12}$.
$d^{+}_{12,22} \geq \beta_{12} - \beta_{22}$ and $d^{-}_{12,22} \geq \beta_{22} - \beta_{12}$.
$d^{+}_{21,22} \geq \beta_{21} - \beta_{22}$ and $d^{-}_{21,22} \geq \beta_{21} - \beta_{22}$.
Objective function will be minimize summation all of variable $d$
In your case you have 4 variables in the matrix, so you have to list all of them. Then in the worst case, you will need to introduce $3 \times 4 \times 2 = 24$ additional variables.

There are 6 pairs of variable (choose 2 from 4) and each pair need $d^+$ and  $d^-$ so should it be $12$ ?

Yes, indeed. You only need $12$ variables. But in my computation, I was listing all the combination of each variable. That's the reason I said there are $24$ variables.
In my experience, these additional 12 variables will not really impact the performance to solve the problem. But, it could be nice to have when you're trying to debug or develop your code or help others to understand.

Will this formula prioritize on improving the outliers first?

Hi @GeoffreyDeSmet , what do you mean the outliers?

@ytsao can you show me 2 examples of the additional 12 variables. I cannot come up with anything in my head

If allocated bandwidth should all ideally be 5, then having one of 8 is worse than having two of 7. The 8 is the outlier.

@TuongNguyenMinh I've updated my answer in above. if you still not clear let me know.

@GeoffreyDeSmet , I think in this case, this formulation can avoid outliers.
Here is an example, since the allocated value in here should be between 0 and 1.
Suppose $A =(1, 1, 0, 0)$, case 1 $B = (0.3, 0.7, 0, 0)$, case 2 $B = (0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)$
The objective value for case 1 is $(0.7-0.3) + 0.3 + 0.7 = 1.4)$, for case 2 is $(0.5-0.5)+0.5+0.5 = 1$ Therefore, if the objective value isn't equal to 1, it means that the solution is not expected.

Well I already able to write down the 12 things in the answer but how to come up with additional variable to make it 24. Can you give me two or three more examples.

@TuongNguyenMinh to have 24 variables, you only need to introduce the variable with existing but swap their index, for example $d^{+}{12,11}$ and $d^{-}{12,11}$, and etc.

@ytsao do you mean $\left{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{d_{12,11}^ +  \ge {\beta _{12}} - {\beta {11}}}\
{d{12,11}^ -  \ge {\beta _{11}} - {\beta _{12}}}
\end{array}} \right.$. Also, I do not understand how this method work ? Would you kindly explain more ?

@TuongNguyenMinh yes, the formula should be like this. These formulations are expressing the difference between two allocated value, your objective is to have same value for each $\beta$, in other words, it means all the difference between allocated $\beta$ should be zero. Therefore, we minimize the sum of variable $d$ in the objective function.

@ytsao Oh I understand it now but what is the role of the huge penalty $M$ for each $d^+$ and each $d^-$ ?

@TuongNguyenMinh $M$ it just a very big number, because we cannot compute the difference by equation, we have to use $d^{+}$ and $d^{-}$ in inequality and to find the minimal value for them, if we didn't put the penalty for them there would be too many possible values for each $d^{+}$ and $d^{-}$. But we only need to find the minimal one from them, I used a huge penalty to do so. If you don't have other terms in your objective function, $M$ could be 1.
